# What will happen to clientx value of a mouseEvent in a RTL situation?

Tags: javascript, html

let's say a green `div` is nested inside another red `div`.

Let's say the mouse event in the center the green box in the following picture

[image]

has the value of `clientX` 30 (red box width is 100)

In a RTL situation, the markup will be displayed like so

[image]

The green box is put to a new location by using `transform: translateX(-pos)`, as opposed to  `transform: translateX(pos)` in normal situation.

Will the `clientX` still carry the value of 30?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even in Right-To-Left mode, coordinating start at left-top with ( 0, 0 ).

And I think to you'd better before questioning it, write a shortcode and test it yourself.

In Right-To-Left mode,

```js
document.querySelector( "#inner" ).addEventListener( "click", e => console.log( e.clientX ) );
```

```css
#outer {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#inner {
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body dir="rtl">
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner">
            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In Left-To-Right mode,

```js
document.querySelector( "#inner" ).addEventListener( "click", e => console.log( e.clientX ) );
```

```css
#outer {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#inner {
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body dir="ltr">
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner">
            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```